# Read only access to H2 Database in Server mode

Tags: java, h2, in-memory-database

Currently I'm accessing H2 Database in server mode and I use JDBC URL like jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/nio:~/source/database/database/ from my java application. By default, the user who accesses has the Read/Write access and I want to restrict it to read-only access.

I've come across the option ACCESS_MODE_DATA=r in the JDBC URL, which would make the H2 DB access read-only but the user who accesses H2 DB could bypass it, if he doesn't pass the option ACCESS_MODE_DATA=r .

Are there any alternate options to restrict the TCP connection to H2 Database as readonly ?

Comment: looks like you can have user with read only access https://stackoverflow.com/a/21192942/175554

Answer (score 0):

Just use `conn.setReadonly(true)` to make the JDBC connection read only.

```
public class JDBCReadonly {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.10.20:9092/path/to/db-file-name"; // replace with your H2 URL
    private static final String USERNAME = "sa"; // replace with your username
    private static final String PASSWORD = ""; // replace with your password

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = connectReadonly();
    }

    public static Connection connectReadonly() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            conn.setReadOnly(true);
            System.out.println("Connected to the H2 database successfully.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```